# Dupehammer closes question, reports that the dupe has an answer, even if there is no answer

Tags: bug, dupehammer

I just voted to close this question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/23901882) as a dupe of this one ([Why does the following code using IOmniThreadPool cause access violations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23907144)). The dupehammer came into play. The closed question now states:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

That statement is not true. The dupe has no answers. This looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dupehammer has absolutely nothing to do with that. That's a standard message that gets displayed on all duplicate questions. The message that changes is in the box at the top, which correctly displays "This question is an exact duplicate of..."

The reason you were even able to submit the vote is because both questions were asked by the same user, which is the only case where a normal user is allowed to cast a duplicate vote targeted at a question with no answers on it.

So this is not really a bug. You could change it to a feature request to have it change the message in that box in these rare cases if it bothers you. It could potentially just use the message already being used by the duplicate box at the top of the post. Generally, though, exact duplicates by the same author should just be deleted outright, <s>so worrying about the message might be a moot point</s>. On second thought, that would be a good idea since the same-author limitation does not exist on Meta sites.

Comment: Nice catch! I did not know about that caveat.